# PHP regex/search and replace multiline strings in multiple files

Tags: php, regex

I have several hundred `.markdown` files that I need to loop through and replace the following multiline strings:

```
---
---
```

I currently have the following code:

```
foreach (glob("*.markdown") as $filename)
{
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
    file_put_contents($filename, preg_replace("/regexhere/","replacement",$file));
}
```

My question is, which regex do I need to remove the multi line strings in every file.

Thanks

Comment: Two calls to `preg_replace()`?

Comment: @KristerAndersson Sorry I meant the regex to remove the multiline `---` strings. I need to match and remove only the multiline `---` because elsewhere in the file I have single `---` which I need to keep

Comment: Sidenote: You may need to remove the `http://localhost/` in `foreach (glob("http://localhost/*.markdown")`

Comment: @Fred-ii- why is that? Could you please explain?

Comment: because you don't want to access the files via a web-server

Comment: Okay cool, I've removed that. Any ideas for the multiline regex?

Comment: i see no reason not to use str_replace

Comment: But how do you specify multiline in str_replace?

Comment: like this:http://codepad.viper-7.com/p1Bant, `\r` or `\n` or both will depend on os

Comment: @Dagon amazing! Thanks so much! Can you please post that as the answer so I can accept it  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be done faster with `str_replace()`, like so:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";

$file="my file
is
this
---
---
goats";

echo str_replace("---\r\n---\r\n",'',$file);
```

which returns:

```
my file
is
this
goats
```

Live Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/p1Bant

line breaks can be `\n` or `\r\n` depending on os\software

Comment: Plus a demo; bonus. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it using Regular expression then you should try this::

```
echo "<pre>";

$file="my file
is---dfdf
this---
---
---
goats";

$res = preg_replace("/^---\r\n/m", "", $file);
// m at the end of line will match multiple line so even if you have --- on more than 2 lines it will work
echo $res;
```

Output will be::

```
my file
is---dfdf
this---
goats
```

Comment: @user2028856 try this if you want to use regex search replace